# How do you make a CSV file take in more than one user

Tags: java, csv, javafx

I successfully created a csv file from the data that I inputted into the textfields, but the problem is that it will only take in one user. I know the problem is that I didn't make my write method static but I can't figure out way a to transfer the data stored in the variable to the csv file without making not static.

```
public class newUserController {

        //private ResourceBundle resources;
        public Button continues;
        public Button save;

        public TextField tf_username;
        public PasswordField pf_password;
        public TextField tf_name;
        public ComboBox<?> dd_selectGender;
        public TextField tf_email;
        public TextField tf_age;
        public TextField tf_height;
        public ComboBox<?> dd_measurment;


        public void savePressed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            String username = tf_username.getText();
            String password = pf_password.getText();
            String name = tf_name.getText();
            String gender = (String) dd_selectGender.getValue();
            String email = tf_email.getText();
            String age =tf_age.getText();
            String height=tf_height.getText();
            String measurment = (String) dd_measurment.getValue();
            CSVBuilder csv = new CSVBuilder(username,password,name,gender,email,age,height,measurment);


        }


        public void continuePressed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            Parent menu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Menu Overview.fxml"));
            Scene menuScene = new Scene(menu);

            Stage window =(Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

            window.setScene(menuScene);
            window.show();
        }



}
```

```
public class CSVBuilder {

     String username;
     String password;
     String name;
     String gender;
     String email;
     String age;
     String height;
     String measurement;

    CSVBuilder(String user, String pass, String nam, String gen, String e_mail, String ag, String hei, String measur){
        username = user;
        password = pass;
        name = nam;
        gender = gen;
        email = e_mail;
        age = ag;
        height = hei;
        measurement = measur;
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\vargh\\eclipse-workspace\\Java\\FitLog.csv";
        writeCsv(filePath);
    }

    //technically should be static
    public void writeCsv(String filePath) {
        //create demo Users
        List<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();
        User user = new User(username,password,name,gender,email,age,height,measurement);
        users.add(user);

        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);         

            fileWriter.append("Username, Password, Name, Gender, E-Mail, Age, Height, Measurement\n");

            for(User u: users) {
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(u.getUsername()));
            fileWriter.append(",");
            fileWriter.append(u.getPassword());
            fileWriter.append(",");
            fileWriter.append(u.getName());
            fileWriter.append(",");
            fileWriter.append(u.getGender());
            fileWriter.append(",");
            fileWriter.append(u.getEmail());
            fileWriter.append(",");
            fileWriter.append(u.getAge());
            fileWriter.append(",");
            fileWriter.append(u.getHeight());
            fileWriter.append(","); 
            fileWriter.append(u.getMeasurement());
            fileWriter.append("\n"); 
           }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
           }catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class User {
    String username;
    String password;
    String name;
    String gender;
    String email;
    String age;
    String height;
    String measurement;
    User(String user, String pass, String nam, String gen, String e_mail, String ag, String hei, String measur){
        username = user;
        password = pass;
        name = nam;
        gender = gen;
        email = e_mail;
        age = ag;
        height = hei;
        measurement = measur;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public String getMeasurement() {
        return measurement;
    }

}
```

Comment: I highly doubt that `static` has anything to do with it. But your `writeCsv()` method is corrupting the CSV either way. You're writing the headers to the file each time you write a new user; this will definitely cause issues when trying to read the data back in.

Answer (score 1):

You're only adding 1 user, right?

```
        List<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();
        User user = new User(username,password,name,gender,email,age,height,measurement);
        users.add(user);
```

Also, would call attention to:

`CSVBuilder csv = new CSVBuilder(username,password,name,gender,email,age,height,measurment);`

Would suggest refactoring that into a `List` of `Users` as such:

```
    CSVBuilder(List<User> users){
        this.users = users;
    }
```

and then you can invoke it with something like:

```
        List<User> users= new ArrayList<>();
        User user = new User("username-1","password-1","alice","f","email@xyz.com","20","","");
        users.add(user);
        User user2 = new User("username-2","password-2","bob","m","email@abc.com","21","","");
        users.add(user2);
        CSVBuilder csvBuilder = new CSVBuilder(users);
        csvBuilder.writeCsv("FitLog.csv");
```

Producing the output:

```
Username, Password, Name, Gender, E-Mail, Age, Height, Measurement
username-1,password-1,alice,f,email@xyz.com,20,,
username-2,password-2,bob,m,email@abc.com,21,,
```

Would also suggest [`FileWriter(File, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)) since it seems like you may be trying to append to the file with a new user / click. Default option doesn't append, but overwrites.